# Confirming Axioms of Vector Spaces that rely on modular arithmetic

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, modular-arithmetic, axioms

V is a vector space where $$V = \{\mathrm{rotations}\} = \{\theta : θ ~ \text{is a real number and} ~ 0 ≤ θ < 2π\}$$

Addition is defined by $$θ_1 + θ_2 := (θ_1 + θ_2) ~ \mathrm{mod} ~ 2π$$

Scaling by real numbers is defined by $$rθ = rθ ~ \mathrm{mod} ~ 2π$$

My question as to do with the axioms of Additive Associativity and Additive Inverses.

AA is defined as $$(u+v)+w=u+(v+w)  \tag{$u,v,w ∈ V$}$$
and AI is defined as: there exists a vector **w** such that **w=-v** where $$v+w=0_v  \tag{$v,w ∈ V$}$$

With regards to AA, I am unsure of how mod2π would effect the addition. So if u=θ1, v=θ2 and w=θ3, then (u+v)+w would be $$((θ_1+θ_2) ~ \mathrm{mod} ~ 2π)+θ_3) ~ \mathrm{mod} ~2π$$ right? How can I prove that is the same thing as $$(θ_1+(θ_2+θ_3) ~ \mathrm{mod} ~2π) ~ \mathrm{mod} ~2π$$ wihtout losing generality? Can the mod be pulled out of the expression and done afterwards since θ is a real number?

Secondly, for AI I assume that $$w=-v$$ would not mean literally negative v, but rather the inverse that would provide the zero vector since there are no negative elements in V. For example, if $$v=3π/2$$ then $$w=π/2$$ then $$v+w=0$$ as defined by the addition of vectors in this space. Am I right in assuming this?

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format both, your questions and your answers :)

Comment: What is the field your vector space is meant to be defined on?

Comment: I believe that the vector field would be **R^1** since the space is that of rotations.

Comment: You are right about additive inverses. $-v$ really means $2\pi - v$.

Comment: @Matt: I meant the field of scalars; field here being the algebraical structure.For example, it might be the real numbers or the complex numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The "mods" can be pulled out of the parentheses. Here's why:

The expression $(\theta_1 + \theta_2) ~ \mathrm{mod} ~ 2\pi$ really means any number of the form $(\theta_1 + \theta_2) + 2k\pi$ where $k$ is an integer. Similarly, the entire expression $((\theta_1 + \theta_2) ~ \mathrm{mod} ~ 2\pi + \theta_3) ~ \mathrm{mod} ~ 2\pi$ is a number of the form

$$ ((\theta_1 + \theta_2) + 2k\pi + \theta_3) + 2m\pi = (\theta_1+\theta_2)+\theta_3 + 2(k+m)\pi = ((\theta_1+\theta_2)+\theta_3) ~ \mathrm{mod} ~ 2\pi
$$

And similarly for $\theta_1 + (\theta_2 + \theta_3)$.

Comment: Awesome, so I was on the right track then! Thank you for both of your answers! I will now close the thread.

Answer (score 0):

See both of u/Nick 's comments for the answer to this question. "Mods" can be pulled out of the expression and the additive inverse would be 2$\pi$ - v.